# Building a website on top of wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm thinking of building a complete website on top of wordpress. The site will be similar to a shopping or a job search site, with moderate complexity.

Is it possible to do so, with my own custom database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is in fact possible.

You'll probably get a better response here though if you ask more specific questions about problems you encounter when trying to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to find special plugins, but if you have your own data structure the better way for you is to write your own modules. But you need to know that the initial idea of wordpress is a blog or site that has a lot of text information. Even if you'll find plugins, you'll need to make them work with your site, sometimes they are incompatible and unsupported.

In your case, I can advice you to use frameworks like Symfony, CakePHP, Lithium, Zend Framework, Yii or whatever.